# Why can't django/python handle long call chains?

Tags: python, django

So, this is an extraordinary odd question, but I have the following code (I'm aware it's not good style, we're ignoring that for this question):

```
request.user.towbeeuser.towbeewreckerbee.fleet_management_user.photo = photo_form.cleaned_data['photo']
request.user.towbeeuser.towbeewreckerbee.fleet_management_user.save()
```

The above code doesn't work, as request.user.towbeeuser.towbeewreckerbee.fleet_management_user.photo  says "The 'photo' attribute has no file associated with it."

However, simply moving the `fleet_management_user` to its own variable such that the code looks like the following works just fine:

```
fm_user = request.user.towbeeuser.towbeewreckerbee.fleet_management_user
fm_user.photo = photo_form.cleaned_data['photo']
fm_user.save()
```

Any idea why this is happening? I can also post the code for the various classes, but I'm not sure how relevant that is.

Comment: Basically one of those attribute accesses is not a normal attribute but rather a new object is created, since it has to do a database lookup. The same thing is serialised from the database twice and it doesn't know that you want to connect them.